# Nextjs Axios only works on 1st call

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, next.js

I'm using NextJs for my project and when I use Axios instead of fetch there is only my 1st call that's working properly.

Imagine that I'm on my page `/home` that got a `getServerSideProps` function. It will work perfectly on the 1st call, the second one will always return `undefined`,  no matter if it's 2xx or 4xx code. If I shut down the dev serv and rerun it, it's working again, but only once....

I'm pretty sure my code is working since I have no problem when using fetch or axios on 1st call but w/e I'll give it to you :

```
home.js
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    const { id } = context.query
    const {produit,error} = await getProduit(id)

    return {
        props:{
            produit:produit??null,
            error:error??null
        }
    }
}
```

```
useCase.js
export function getProduit(id){
    return getRequest(`produit/${id}`)
    .then(response => {
        const produit = response.produit
        const adapter = new AdapterProduit(produit)
        return {produit:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(adapter.toArrayProduit()))[0]}
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return {error:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({status:err?.status,message:err?.data?.err}))}
    })
}
```

```
backFacade.js
const BACK_END_SERVER = 'http://localhost:3000/api'

const axios = require('axios');

export function getRequest(ressource){
    const token = '' //localStorage.getItem('token')
    return axios.get(`${BACK_END_SERVER}/${ressource}`,
    {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}})
}

//Interceptors
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response.data
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error.response);
});
```

Thank for the help

Comment: Look like the problem came from your BE. Have you tried to fetch a different endpoint to see if your FE is already properly configured?

Comment: Hi, I've tried ther endpoint and thing that's weird it's if I console.log('toto') then change to console.log('tata') it will show toto / tata , like there is a cache or smth that trigger the old version and the new one.
When I log my back-end return, it's the good datas, but I can't be sure since I have this problem of 'cache'.
Plus, if I have 2 calls on the same page, the 1st one will work and the second one will return undefined... And everything works when I'm using fetch instead of axios

Comment: And to add more informations, I have no problem when I run build + run start